# MonoTouch.Dialog: StringElement with value, but hide value in UI?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I want the user to select one out of many elements.

So I'm creating a long list of `StringElement`, each one with a specific caption. Each element is associated with a specific value. My ideas was to set the `Value` property of the `StringElement`. However, this makes the value being shown on the right side of the element.

How can I hide this value? I only need it when the user tapped an entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the most basic settings-like dialog I end up (90% of the time) defining my own `Element` types. It solves many issues (like this one) and reduce duplicated code.

So you get something like:

```
class MyStringElement : StringElement {
  public MyStringElement (string caption, string hiddenValue) : base (caption) {
      HiddenValue = hiddenValue;
  }

  public string HiddenValue { get; set; }
}
```

You might also want to use the `caption` as the key to (an existing?) `Dictionary<string,string>` to reduce the memory requirement of each element (depending on how long your list turns out to be). In any case having your own `Element` type makes it easier to change its storage/behaviour in the future (with minimal impact elsewhere in your code).

Comment: I did exactly this meanwhile and I even named the property "HiddenValue" :-) Thanks.